# Handling a URI as a request parameter in Semantic Web applications

Tags: java, uri, semantic-web, jena

Over the last few years, on a number of applications, I've used RDF as a data model and used Jena to manage and query the data. For new applications I try to design applications to be RESTful and URLs in the application usually have some representation in the RDF. For example:

http://example.com/foo/bar/1/

However, occasionally you need to drill down or call a URI from a servlet in a request parameter:

http://example.com/foo/bar/1/?id=http://example.com/foo/bar/xyz/

The URLs get pretty ugly and unfriendly, especially when encoded:

http://example.com/foo/bar/1/?id=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffoo%2Fbar%2Fxyz%2F

Is there a best practice in design? Should I be creating a separate shorter value than a URI in the RDF that I can query on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure there's a great deal you can do about this generally. If you thing about other web application the established standard is relative URLs, that is resolve the id argument against the request url:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/1/?id=/foo/bar/xyz/
http://example.com/foo/bar/1/?id=../xyz/
```

(encode as needed)

That helps in the provided examples since the two urls are in the same domian. Otherwise I suppose you just have to accept full urls.

Prefixes are commonly used in the RDF world, of course, but it doesn't feel very RESTful unless you provide a means to find out the mappings.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a known, or knowable, set of prefixes then abbreviating URI's to q-names is a pattern I've used in the past:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/1/?id=example:xyz
```

In the [linked data API](http://code.google.com/p/linked-data-api/wiki/Specification), short-names for entities can be declared in the configuration, typically by stating which property of a resource is used to denote its short name (e.g: `rdfs:label` or `skos:notation`). So the pattern there is to use a small amount of configuration information to provide name abbreviations via the RDF model itself.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, see similar posts on answers.semanticweb.com:

- [http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/13756/passing-uris-as-parameters-best-practices](https://web.archive.org/web/20160524201820/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/13756/passing-uris-as-parameters-best-practices)
- [http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/16159/creating-dereferenceable-uris-for-new-resources](https://web.archive.org/web/20130831070750/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/16159/creating-dereferenceable-uris-for-new-resources)
- [http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/15037/tools-to-publish-dereferencable-linked-data](https://web.archive.org/web/20131011132837/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/15037/tools-to-publish-dereferencable-linked-data)

You might want to consider storing resources in a SPARQL endpoint, making them dereferenceable with the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} (text/turtle|application/rdf+xml)
RewriteRule !^/sparql /sparql?query=CONSTRUCT\s{?s\s?p\s?o}\sWHERE\s{?s\s?p\s?o.\s<%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}%{QUERY_STRING}>\s?p\s?o} [L,R=303]
```

I think in general dereferencing the URI is far preferable to passing the URI as a query string. Depending on your framework, you may even be able to use a URI as a primary key for a domain object (possible on GRAILS and RAILS).